# how to set the columnvalues to a variable in store procedure

Tags: sql-server

using a strored procedure i get a field like this

### FileNo

0001
0002
0003

how to get this as 0001,0002,0003

pls help..

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
select FileId, REPLACE(FileNum, ' ', ', ') from table
```

Comment: DECLARE @FullNames VARCHAR(100)

SELECT
    @FullNames = ISNULL(@FullNames,'') + FileNum + ', ' 
FROM table

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you mean?

```
declare @variable nvarchar(250)

select @variable = f1 + ',' + f2 + ',' f3 from table
```

Comment: not this way, if i have fields
Fileid | FileNum
---------------
1         0001
1         0002

i want it as
Fileid | FileNum
---------------
1         0001,0002

Comment: pls consider Fileid,filenum as the fields of a table and the rest its values

Comment: I want to concatenate the row values based on a Field for eg(FileID)